# Concat in php not the right file path

Tags: php

Im trying to get an image called what ever the user submits.png from the tmp folder and put it in the folder of Business_Names/whatever the user enters. Im having trouble concating in php the error it gives me is that the file doesnt exists

```
 $filename = str_replace(" ","_", trim($username) ); 
    mkdir("Business_Pages/". $filename."/");
    if( $fp = fopen("Business_Pages/". $filename . "/" . $filename . ".php", "w") )
    {
      fwrite($fp,"<?php session_start();");
      fwrite($fp,"if(isset(\$_SESSION['id'])) { ?>");

      fwrite($fp, $doctype.$htmlOpen.$head.$bodyOpen.$header.$wcImage.$accountTable.$linksTable.$bodyClose.$htmlClose);

      fwrite($fp,"<?php } else { echo \"User not logged in\";} ?>");
      fclose($fp);
    }

    $tmpdir = "tmp/";
    $userdir = "Business_Pages/ . $filename . '/' ";
    rename("$tmpdir . $filename . '/' . '.png'",
           "$userdir . $filename . '/' '.png'");
```

Comment: can you copy here the error message that you get?

Comment: Copying from the `tmp` folder? If you allow the user to upload files, you should use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move it.

Comment: i used move_uploaded_file() to move it to tmp

Comment: Warning: rename(tmp/ . . '/' . '.png',Business_Pages/ . . '/' . . '/' .'.png') [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/content/96/10688096/html/verify.php on line 90

Comment: i opened the script directly so $filename isnt defined

Answer (score 0):

Just went through your code.

Why haven't you used the concatenation operator in the last line of your code?

You have posted: `"$userdir . $filename . '/' '.png'");`

It should be: `"$userdir . $filename . '/' . '.png'");`

Please check it.

Thank you

Comment: thanks for helping me find that however it still isnt placing it in the folder